# How to pop to root dialog with bot framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using the .Net backend for my bot based on the bot framework.
In one of my dialogs I give the user the option to return to the root dialog - or at least, that's what I'm trying to do but no success. Here's what I have already tried:

- call `context.Reset()` - I learned that I may not use this from inside a dialog; it causes a crash
- `Conversation.SendAsync((IMessageActivity)context.Activity, () => new RootDialog())` - does not seem to do anything

Ideally I just want to get back to what is first on the stack without having to hardcode the `RootDialog` type.

Comment: context.Done is not enough?

Comment: But what if dialog A took me to B, took me to C. Done() gets me to B, but not to A. Or should I not worry about the stack and just forward to the dialog I want to go to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Ezequiel, context.Done() is how to end the current dialog, and return control to the calling dialog.

[https://docs.botframework.com/.../sdkreference/dialog_stack.html](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/de/db4/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_internals_1_1_i_dialog_stack.html#ac925ad5a83a7d931925c575d31eb9575)

> void Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.IDialogStack.Done(R value)
>
> Complete the current dialog and return a result to the parent dialog.
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
>  value: The value of the result.
> ```

Comment: I don't want to go to the _calling_ dialog but to the _root_ dialog. A -> B -> C; `Done()` gets me to B but not to A.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot call .done () from c and then b?

Comment: I can of course do that but I wondered if it is the correct way to do it. Seems somewhat counterintuitive.

Comment: Yeah, managing a dialog stack in a restful service is inherently complex.

Comment: context.Call(new RootDialog(), null) from any dialog.

Comment: @TomCat This was working in BotFramework v3, but in v4 the Call-method does not exist.